# Is this responsible and defensive, or paranoid and obsessive?

Tags: c#

Sometimes there's a fine line between being safe and running scared.

Does this code cross the line into scaredy-cat zone?

```
DuckbillPlatypusForm dbpf = null;
if (radioButtonUseExistingPlatypus.Checked) {
    dbpf = new DuckbillPlatypusForm(DuckbillSetupUtils.DuckbillPlatypusState.Readonly, funnyMammalIDs);
} else if (radioButtonCreateNewFromExistingPlatypus.Checked) {
    dbpf = new DuckbillPlatypusForm(DuckbillSetupUtils.DuckbillPlatypusState.Template, funnyMammalIDs);
} else if (radioButtonCreateNewPlatypus.Checked) {
    dbpf = new DuckbillPlatypusForm(DuckbillSetupUtils.DuckbillPlatypusState.StartNew, funnyMammalIDs);
}
if (null != dbpf)
{
    dbpf.Show();
}
```

After all, there are only three radio buttons, and one is checked at design time, so dbpf can never be null, right? Unless somehow all of the radio buttons become unchecked at design-time, or I add another radio button without updating this code, and that one gets selected, but at what point do I just "bite the bullet" and accept suchlike risks?

Comment: In my opinion, never - this is excellent code, really, and one can never be too safe.. Unless it's at the expense of code readability, which it isn't in this case.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could probably accomplish the same thing with a Switch statement as well but your code looks good I rather be safe than sorry

Comment: @L.B I don't think he was looking for a review of this specific code, despite the title.. I think he was looking for advice on when to accept programming risks, no matter how unlikely they are. It might be more suitable in the Programmers website, though..

Comment: Too much duplication in code. It can be simplified further, without unneccessary NULL check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking for null is good in my opinion, because there is a chance that another radio button will be added in future. Maybe from another developer of your team (not yourself), and perhaps it's quite some time in the future.

Maybe it would be even better to handle it as an exception, if the variable is null, because that would certainly be an error in the code, and should be fixed.

**Edit:**

If you rearrange your code a little bit, the exception thing would become very natural. Just separate the reading from the GUI.

```
function DuckbillSetupUtils.DuckbillPlatypusState StateFromGui()
{
  if (radioButtonUseExistingPlatypus.Checked)
    return DuckbillSetupUtils.DuckbillPlatypusState.Readonly;
  if (radioButtonCreateNewFromExistingPlatypus.Checked)
    return DuckbillSetupUtils.DuckbillPlatypusState.Template;
  if (radioButtonCreateNewPlatypus.Checked)
    return DuckbillSetupUtils.DuckbillPlatypusState.StartNew;
  else
    return DuckbillSetupUtils.DuckbillPlatypusState.Undefined;
}

new DuckbillPlatypusForm(StateFromGui(), funnyMammalIDs);
```

Now if the constructor is called with State `Undefined`, you can throw an exception. This way, if you add another radiobutton, you have to update only this `StateFromGui` function, and you have a single point to test the state.

Comment: +1 -- I was half way through writing up this same response, throwing an exception (such as `NotImplementedException`) would help protect against another developer (or yourself) adding another radio button and forgetting to implement the code for it.

Comment: @JonWarnerNet - Good to hear that others think likewise.

Comment: Agreed.  Just to add another perspective, I've seen times in some languages/frameworks when automated testing of an application through the UI runs too quickly (lack of realistic delays between actions) and the user interface may or may not be in a consistent state when the event handlers fire.  Code styled like this may have a better chance of catching this sort of problem and saving some development time.